# How can I use a field of a Dart class as value in my ValueNotifier?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the ValueNotifier class in my last project.
I tried to set my class as a type for the ValueNotifier object:
This is the snippet I'm working on:

`final ValueNotifier<Person> p = ValueNotifier<Person>(Person());`

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Person value, Widget child) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('${value.marriageStatus}'),                    
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: p,
            ),
```

```
enum marriageStatus {
  SINGLE,
  MARRIED,
  WIDOW
}

class Person{

  marriageStatus marriageState = marriageStatus.SINGLE;

  //Constructor
  Person(){
    print("Constructor without arguments");
  }

  //Getters
  marriageStatus get currentState{
    return marriageState;
  }
}
```

As I found later it doesn't catch the changes in the fields of the class.
I would like to set as **valueListenable** the `p.marriageState`, in order to change the text when the state changes.

My question is:

Can I use ValueNotifier in another way in order to work or should I use another class? (like ChangeNotifier)

Thanks

**UPDATE 2021-02-22**

I changed the code accordingly to a suggestion in order to override == operator and check for the changes in the fields, but it still does not work.

```
enum marriageStatus {
  SINGLE,
  MARRIED,
  WIDOW
}
class Person extends Equatable {
  marriageStatus marriageState = marriageStatus.SINGLE;

  //Constructor
  Person(){
    print("Constructor without arguments");
  }

  //Getters
  marriageStatus get currentState{
    return marriageState;
  }
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [marriageState];
}
```

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool flag = true;
  void changeStatus(){
    if(flag){
      p.value.marriageState = marriageStatus.SINGLE;
      flag = false;
      print("the name is ${p.value.marriageState}");
    }
    else{
      p.value.marriageState = marriageStatus.WIDOW;
      flag = true;
      print("the name is ${p.value.marriageState}");
    }
  }

  ValueNotifier<Person> p = ValueNotifier<Person>(Person());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:           
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Person value, Widget child) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('${value.marriageState}'),
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: p,
            )
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FlatButton(
              child: Text("changeStatus"),
              onPressed: changeStatus,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A `ValueNotifier` is watching for its value to change, according to `==`.  As you probably have not overridden that to be deep equality for `Person`, it's still identity, which doesn't change when you change member variables.  Look for https://pub.dev/packages/equatable as one possible solution.

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and I thought that was the correct one, but despite the use of "equatable", it doesn't work.
I change the *marriageState* correctly but it doesn't update the widget accordingly unless I manually press hot reload.

I will update the question with the changes you suggested.